Spring Cloud GCP PubSub Tracing using OpenTelemetry vs Spring Cloud Trace
I'm trying to trace PubSub messaging across different Spring microservices. We are running two Spring microservices on GKE. Service 1 publishes to PubSub and Service 2 subscribes to the same topic. We use the spring-cloud-gcp-trace lib for Tracing in our services.
I see two approaches to trace PubSubMessages

OpenTelemetry Tracing in the Publisher & Subscriber https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/open-telemetry-tracing
Using TracePubSubAutoConfiguration with spring-cloud-gcp-trace (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/main/spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spring/autoconfigure/trace/pubsub)

There are no examples for the second option. With option 1, I see examples where I can trace the message from the publisher to subscriber with time spent in the client libraries. But with option 2 I'm not sure if we will be able to do that. As the spring-cloud-gcp-trace uses Brave instrumentation and not necessarily OpenTelemetry. The Publisher and Subscriber API requires OpenTelemetrySdk
The questions are

Are these two different things and can coexist?
Can I use the trace
lib to get the kind of tracing I would get from the open telemetry
option?

Thanks

The OpenTelemetry instrumentation for the Pub/Sub Java client is implemented within the com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher and com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber classes, which the Pub/Sub Spring client is built on top of. It is a separate implementation from TracePubSubAutoConfiguration with spring-cloud-gcp-trace and thus both the OpenTelemetry and Brave instrumentations can be used at the same time.
Since the OpenTelemetry instrumentation is implemented at a lower level (the actual Publisher and Subscriber client classes as opposed to a wrapper of them), it allows for more a detailed trace of your messages within Pub/Sub, including flow control, batching, and lease management. This same level of detail is not possible when using just the spring-cloud-gcp-trace Brave instrumentation.
In order to enable OpenTelemetry instrumentation for a Pub/Sub Spring client, you need to will need to implement a custom PublisherFactory that instantiates an OpenTelemetry instance with the required tracers, exporters, etc. The sample for the Pub/Sub Java client can be used as an example for this.
